# How to replace CHAR(13) in DB varchar(6000)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion

Using ColdFusion and Microsoft SQL we are exporting data to an Excel Spreadsheet using the cfx_excel plugin. The data contains a varchar(6000) which has CHAR(13)/line-breaks inputted in each entry.

The line-breaks are appearing as square brackets every time the report is generated in Excel format.

How would I go about removing the CHAR(13) within a SQL query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
update YourTable
set YourColumn =replace(YourColumn,CHAR(13),'')
```

or just for a select

```
SELECT replace(YourColumn,CHAR(13),'')
FROM YourTable
```

for char(10) and char(13) you can do this

```
SELECT replace(replace(YourColumn,CHAR(13),''),CHAR(10),'')
FROM YourTable
```

'' will replace it with a blank, if you want a space then use ' ' instead of ''

Comment: Is this possible with a SELECT MyTable?

Comment: This is so close to working :)

Is there a way for me to replace two items (CHAR13 and CHAR10) per REPLACE?

,replace(n.NOTE,CHAR(10),'') as [Comments]

Comment: see 3rd query, you can nest REPLACE

Comment: char(13)char(10) = \r\n, aka carriage return + newline, which is what windows line breaks are made of.  A single replace will do.

SELECT REPLACE(YourField,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'') AS YourField 
FROM YourTable

Comment: As a note, if you do this as an update (and on insert for new records) it will be a good bit more efficient than doing it on every select in your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

To replace both char(10) and char(13) you should be able to just do a

```
replaceList(textToReplaceIn,"#chr(10)#,#chr(13)#",",")
```

If that doesn't work you can just do 2 replaces as in

```
replace(replace(textToReplaceIn,chr(10),"","all"),chr(13),"","all")
```